# Showing JPG image with Qt does not work with release executable

Tags: c++, qt, release, executable, jpeg

i have a annoying issue with showing jpg images with qt. I devlope with Visual Studio 2008 in Windows 7 and using the Qt version 4.8.2. I will now describe my problem by means of the "collidingmice" example deliverd with Qt (../examples/graphicsview/collidingmice).

I can build this example via Visual Studio IDE or with via the Visual Studio command prompt. In this example a jpg is used as background and is correctly shown when I execute the debug executable. But in release build this background jpg is not shown.

I already realized, that Qt uses plugins for loading/showing different images. Therefore I copied the contents of the plugin folder of Qt into the application directory (where collidingmice.exe is). Unfortunatly, this does not solve the problem.

Hence, I thought there must be something wrong with the Qt build and the jpeg library. Therefore, I reconfigured Qt by executing the following commands in the Visual Studio command prompt:

```
nmake distclean
configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2008 -qt-libjpeg -no-webkit
nmake
```

After that did a rebuild of the example, but again the jpg image is not shown. I am not sure what the problem is since it works in debug build and in release I think I only have to deliver the needed plugin DLLs. But obviously I am not right.

I hope anyone can help me or can give me some hints where the problem might be. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Therefore I copied the contents of the plugin folder of Qt into the
>   application directory (where collidingmice.exe is).

You need to put the plugins into an "imageformats" subdirectory, e.g. like

```
bin
 ├── collidingmice.exe
 └── imageformats
       ├── qjpeg4.dll
       ├ ...
```

See also http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/46927-Location-of-imageformats-directory

---

It turned out that the OP had already set up the directory structure accordingly. The root cause was that a wrong QtGui4.dll has been loaded. This can be fixed *"by copying the DLL directly into the application directory or by changing the order of the paths in the PATH environment variable so that your Qt bin directory is placed in front of all other paths containing a QtGui4.dll."*

In any case, the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is a good tool to track down such issues.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I already did this and it does not work.

Comment: @Owen too sad - that was exactly the issue I had some time ago ... Then, I suggest that you use the process monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) or the DependencyWalker application (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see which DLLs the system tries to load.

Comment: Just to be sure: For your release build, you have copied the release dlls into the imageformats directory, right? Means, e.g. qjpeg4.dll and not qjpegd4.dll.

Comment: Yes that right. But, thanks for the link with the process monitor - nice tool. I determined some problems with this tool regarding the QtGui4.dll. I have the suspicion that a wrong QtGui4.dll will be loaded. I am testing this currently.

Comment: Fixed! The wrong QtGui4.dll was loaded (from MikTeX). It can be fixed by copying the DLL directly into the application directory or by changing the order of the paths in the PATH environment variable so that your Qt bin directory is placed in front of all other paths containing a QtGui4.dll - Thanks for the Process Monitor tool :)