# QGraphicsObject doesn't display QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I'm developing a very simple application on win7 and running on win8.
When I run on win7 it shows the pixmap drawn by my `QGraphicsObject` subclass. However when I copy the exe and dll's to the my tablet it doesn't show the pixmap but everything else is the same.

Another problem is when I quit the application it says unexpectedly closed.

Here are the related parts

```
myImage::myImage(QGraphicsObject *parent) :
QGraphicsObject(parent)
{
    pxm = new QPixmap("://images/flower.jpg");
    setScale(0.5);
}

QRectF myImage::boundingRect() const
{
    QRectF rect(0,0,pxm->width(),pxm->height());
    return rect;
}

void myImage::paint( QPainter* painter,
                     const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* /*option*/,
                     QWidget* /*widget*/ )
{
    painter->drawPixmap( 0, 0, pxm->width(), pxm->height(), *pxm );
}
```

And here is the main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene scene;

    myImage img;
    scene.addItem(&img);

    QGraphicsView view(&scene);

    QWidget window;
    window.setFixedHeight(400);
    window.setFixedWidth(500);
    window.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed);

    QPushButton button("Quit");
    QObject::connect(&button,SIGNAL(clicked()),&app,SLOT(quit()));

    QVBoxLayout layout;
    layout.addWidget(&view);
    layout.addWidget(&button);

    window.setLayout(&layout);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using a jpeg image, which isn't native to Qt. In the installation of Qt you'll find a plugins folder with a folder called "imageformats". If you copy the folder of libraries to the path of the executable (assuming Windows), then this should work. A similar discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800346/showing-jpg-image-with-qt-does-not-work-with-release-executable).

Alternatively, use a different image format to jpeg.