# Qt application not displaying my image

Tags: qt, qt-resource

Within the Qt application I created, I added a .jpeg image.

When I run the application on any other system other than mine, I do not see the image in the app window.

How do I rectify this issue ?
I am not well versed with Qt, so please give me a simple and easy way out of this issue.

Comment: Did you properly install the image format plugins? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800346/showing-jpg-image-with-qt-does-not-work-with-release-executable

Comment: Where are you loading the image from? If you're loading the image from a file, you need to make sure the image is available on your target machine as well.

Comment: I did that. I put my image in the same folder as the executable, but it doesn;t work.

Comment: How do you locate the image? (Relative paths are fragile as they rely on the working directory - better use QApplicationDirPath() + “image.png” or bundle it as Qt resource.

Comment: I tried to add a resource file. But thats where I faced issue. Is there any link which gives a pictorial step-by-step on how to add/use a resource file, for AT 5.x?

Comment: Qt docs explain it pretty well